# How to send email using PHP

Tags: php

```
<?php
$message = "Line 1\r\nLine 2\r\nLine 3";
$message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");
$retval=mail('xxx@gmail.com', 'My Subject', $message);
 if( $retval == true )
     {
        echo "Message sent successfully...";
     }else {
            echo "Message could not be sent...";
           }
?>
```

It gives me message as Message could not be sent .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using PHP mail( )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954853/using-php-mail)

Comment: You need `.` before `=` on second `$message`. Try this: `$message .= wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");`

Comment: add this line in your code " echo $mail->ErrorInfo;

Comment: check SMTP server setting if you are testing in localhost

Comment: Most likely your server is not permitting you to use the php mail function....for obvious reasons.

Comment: are you working on online server or localhost

Answer (score -1):

Yor problem is here: `$message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");`
you neet to add `.=` 
 It is the same as `$message = $message . "wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n")";`